# How can position relative make a dom node paint over a position fixed one?

Tags: html, css

I was building a modal, and I was having problems keeping the background behind the main content.
They were on the correct hierarchy for them being painted correctly: the ones behind comes first.
The problem was that the absolute position background was "hidding" the content, despite the content should be painted after and therefore in front.

Suddenly I realised that adding position relative to the content make it render on top of the background, so the background-color of the background was not "masking" it anymore.

Here is a fiddle where you can see how the content with the  position absolute has the correct colors, while the one with normal position has it's colors tinted red.

```css
.main {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(100, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
}

.norelative {
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 1rem
}
```

```html
<div>
Just some basic text
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <div class="content">Content</div>
  <div class="norelative">No relative</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/danielo515/x3u2Lth7/11/

How is this possible? How can position relative affect this layering problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about stacking contexts. Using a `position` property that isn't `static` (the default) makes the element render on top of anything else that is `static`. So, your background renders on top of the static norelative div, but since the relative div isn't `static`, it follows the normal rendering order and renders on top of the background.

See [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for more details.